# XML : Remove parent, clone to siblings

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

My source xml:

```
<company>

  <pricelist>
    <category></category>
    <subcategory></subcategory>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    // x number of items
  </pricelist>

  <pricelist>
    <category></category>
    <subcategory></subcategory>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    // x number of items
  </pricelist>

  // x number of pricelists

</company>
```

Now, would like to build an editor for given xml that automatically:

**I. Removes all the unwanted parents, based on their children attribute values.**

*In my example: Delete all `<pricelist>` where `<category>` is x,y.*

> I partially solved this one. The selection is `/company/pricelist[category[@id='90' or @id='89']]` that now has to be removed, probably `removeChild();`

**II. Clone `<category>` and `<subcategory>` into all sibling `<item>`s.**

I have no clues yet how to start on this one. I was thinking of a loop which goes through all the pricelists, copies their `<category>` and `<subcategory>` and somehow clones them to the each of the sibling `<item>` inside the pricelist (category and subcategory are unique under each pricelist).

*Step II result:*

```
<pricelist>
  <category>cat1</category>
  <subcategory>sub1</subcategory>
  <item>
    <category>cat1</category>
    <subcategory>sub1</subcategory>
  </item>
  <item>
    <category>cat1</category>
    <subcategory>sub1</subcategory>
  </item>
  <item>
    <category>cat1</category>
    <subcategory>sub1</subcategory>
  </item>
  ...
</pricelist>
```

Comment: With this structure you need two nested loops.

Comment: Please add your JS code to the question.

Comment: Will update question with my initial javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said: Two loops. The first selects all remaining price lists, the second iterates over all `item` tags. Filling them with the cloned `category` and `subcategory`.

```js
//DO NOT USE THIS SECTION, THIS IS ONLY TO PARSE THE XML STRING SAMPLE INTO A VALID DOCUMENT

        var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
  xmlDoc.preserveWhiteSpace = false;
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(document.querySelector("textarea").value.trim(),"text/xml");

//END

//first delete the unwanted pricelist

var unwanted = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("pricelist > category[id='89'], pricelist > category[id='90']");
Array.prototype.map.call(unwanted, function(element){
    element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode); //elements deleted
});

//now parse the rest

//The first loop will select all pricelists and iterates over them using Array.prototype.map.
var priceLists = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll("pricelist");
Array.prototype.map.call(priceLists, function(element){
    //select the category and sub
    var cat = element.getElementsByTagName("category")[0];
    var subCat = element.getElementsByTagName("subcategory")[0];

    //now select all item tags. Iterate over them with a normal loop for more clarity.
    var items = element.getElementsByTagName("item");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
    {
         var temp = cat.cloneNode(true); //clone the category
         var temp2 = subCat.cloneNode(true); //clone the subcategory
         items[i].appendChild(temp); //append them
         items[i].appendChild(temp2);
    }
});

//    display the XML :: NOT PART OF THE SOLUTION CODE

document.getElementById("display").value = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(xmlDoc.documentElement);
```

```html
<textarea>

<company>

  <pricelist>
    <category>test 1</category>
    <subcategory>test 2</subcategory>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
  </pricelist>

  <pricelist>
    <category>test 3</category>
    <subcategory>test 4</subcategory>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
  </pricelist>

  <pricelist >
    <category id="90"></category>
    <subcategory></subcategory>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
  </pricelist>
  
   <pricelist >
    <category id="89"></category>
    <subcategory></subcategory>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
    <item></item>
  </pricelist> 
  
  
</company>
  
  </textarea>
<textarea id="display" style="width: 400px; height: 500px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks for the assistance. I will also update the question with my initial javascript code.